# How to use prepend hide fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making chat system with jQuery and Bootstrap

I want to show three message at the same time.

I want to show `msg1` and `msg2` normally then let `msg3` fade in:

```
$('#chat-history').prepend(msg1)
$('#chat-history').prepend(msg2) 
$('#chat-history').prepend(msg3).hide().fadeIn(500);
```

But it makes every message fade in.

I want to let only the last message fade in.

How can I make it?

Comment: msg1, msg2, msg3 are text strings or DOM elements or jQueryobject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#chat-history').prepend(msg1, msg2, msg3);

$(msg3).hide().fadeIn(500); // if msg3 is already a jQuery object, you can omit the $() wrapping function
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. For clarification: `.prepend` returns `$this`, which is the `$('#chat-history')` element. Try removing the effects and putting them on `msg3` instead.

Comment: it works perfectly as I want. thank you .I understood the reason too.